# Tant Fant Game in Python

Tags: python, game, tic-tac-toe

Here is our code of [Tant Fant Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tant_Fant). Does anyone have suggestions for how to improve our code?

```
class board:
    loc = []
    def __init__(self) :
        self.loc = ['B', 'B', 'B', '', '', '', 'W', 'W', 'W']

    def cur_state(self) :
        return self.loc

    def find_empty_spot(self) :
        return [i + 1 for i, j in enumerate(self.cur_state()) if j == '']

    def set_piece(self, pos, piece) :
        self.loc[pos-1] = piece

    def set_state(self, state) :
        for i in range(len(state)) :
            self.loc[i] = state[i]

    # update the board
    def do_move(self, pos, move, cur_board) :
        empty_spot = cur_board.find_empty_spot()
        cur_piece = cur_board.loc[pos-1]
        update_board = board()
        update_board.set_state(cur_board.cur_state())

        if move == 'right' :
            next_pos = pos + 1
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'left' :
            next_pos = pos - 1
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'up' :
            next_pos = pos - 3
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'down' :
            next_pos = pos + 3
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'upleft' :
            next_pos = pos - 4
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'upright' :
            next_pos = pos - 2
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'downleft' :
            next_pos = pos + 2
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        elif move == 'downright' :
            next_pos = pos + 4
            if next_pos in empty_spot :
                update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
                update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
                return update_board
        else :
            return None

    # black piece : 'X'
    # white piece : 'W'
    def print_board(self) :
        next_line = 1
        cur_loc = self.cur_state()
        # print cur_loc
        for pos in cur_loc :
            if pos == 'B' :
                print 'X |',
            elif pos == 'W' :
                print 'O |',
            else :
                print '  |',
            if next_line % 3 == 0 :
                print ""
                print "-----------"
                next_line = 1
            else :
                next_line += 1

class player:

    black_player_pieces = 3
    white_player_pieces = 3
    cur_turn = ''
    move_rules = {1 : ['right', 'down', 'downright',],\
                        2 : ['left', 'right', 'down'],\
                        3 : ['left', 'down', 'downleft'],\
                        4 : ['up', 'down', 'right'],\
                        5 : ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'upleft', 'upright', 'downleft', 'downright'],\
                        6 : ['left', 'up', 'down'],\
                        7 : ['up', 'right', 'upright'],\
                        8 : ['up', 'left', 'right'],\
                        9 : ['up', 'upleft', 'left']
        }

    def __init__(self) :
        self.cur_turn = 'W'

    def next_turn(self, turn) :
        if turn == 'W' :
            self.cur_turn = 'B'
        else :
            self.cur_turn = 'W'

    def gen_move(self, pos, board) :
        turn = self.cur_turn
        self.next_turn(turn)
        next_moves = self.move_rules[pos]
        return [next_moves, pos, board]

    def primitive(self, cur_board) :
        def all_same_pieces(line) :
            elem = line[0]
            flag = True
            for piece in line :
                if piece != elem :
                    flag = False
            return flag

        def who_wins(self) :
            if self.cur_turn == 'W' :
                return 'B'
            else :
                return 'W'

        state = cur_board.cur_state()
        checklists = [[state[0], state[4], state[8]],\
                    [state[3], state[4], state[5]],\
                    [state[2], state[4], state[6]],\
                    [state[0], state[3], state[6]],\
                    [state[1], state[4], state[7]],\
                    [state[2], state[5], state[8]]]
        res = "UNDECIDED"
        for each_list in checklists :
            if "" in each_list :
                continue
            if all_same_pieces(each_list) == False :
                continue 
            res = who_wins(self)
        return res


def main() :
    print "start Tant Fant"
    tf_board = board()
    tf_player = player()
    tf_board.print_board()
    while True :
        res = tf_player.primitive(tf_board)
        if res != 'UNDECIDED' :
            print res,
            print "WIN!"
            return
        print "which side to play?",
        print tf_player.cur_turn
        pos = input("input your position:")
        next_moves, pos, tf_board = tf_player.gen_move(pos, tf_board)
        print "next_moves: ",
        print next_moves
        move = raw_input("input your move: ")
        tf_board = tf_board.do_move(pos, move, tf_board)
        tf_board.print_board()


    '''
    tant_fant_board = board()
    tant_fant_player = player()
    next_moves, cur_pos, cur_board = tant_fant_player.gen_move(1, tant_fant_board)
    for move in next_moves :
        update_board =  tant_fant_board.do_move(cur_pos, move, cur_board)
        if update_board :
            update_board.print_board()
    '''

    print "game over"

main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Fail Fast, Fail Loudly

If `move` is not an allowed value the function just return `None`, instead you could make it fail loudly with a clear error message:

```
def do_move(self, pos, move, cur_board) :
    if move not in ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'upleft', 'upright', 'downleft', 'downright']:
        raise ValueError("Move not in allowed options")
    # Rest of function
```

#### Avoidance of repetition

```
    elif move == 'down' :
        next_pos = pos + 3
        if next_pos in empty_spot :
            update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
            update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
            return update_board
    elif move == 'upleft' :
        next_pos = pos - 4
        if next_pos in empty_spot :
            update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
            update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
            return update_board
    ...
```

This block is repeated every time:

```
        if next_pos in empty_spot :
            update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
            update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
            return update_board
```

So you can write it to the bottom:

```
    if move == 'right' :
        next_pos = pos + 1
    elif move == 'left' :
        next_pos = pos - 1
    elif move == 'up' :
        next_pos = pos - 3
    # All other if branches containing only `next_pos` assignement

    if next_pos in empty_spot :
        update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
        update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
        return update_board
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go slightly further than [@Caridorc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54718/caridorc) in [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147028/98493) and use a dictionary to map from the `move` to the `next_pos`:

```
translation = {'right': 1,
               'left': -1,
               'up': -3, 
               ...}

try:
    next_pos = pos + translation[move]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError("Move not in allowed options")

if next_pos in empty_spot :
    update_board.set_piece(pos, '')
    update_board.set_piece(next_pos, cur_piece)
    return update_board
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to initialize loc in class creation if you will still overwrite it when instance is created

```
class board:
    loc = []
    def __init__(self) :
        self.loc = ['B', 'B', 'B', '', '', '', 'W', 'W', 'W']
```

Now this:

```
def find_empty_spot(self) :
    return [i + 1 for i, j in enumerate(self.cur_state()) if j == '']
```

Enumerate takes start index as second argument so you can just do:

```
def find_empty_spot(self) :
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(self.cur_state(), 1) if j == '']
```

You can simplify this method:

```
def set_state(self, state) :
    for i in range(len(state)) :
        self.loc[i] = state[i]
```

If loc and state are guaranteed to be the same size, you can just do:

```
def set_state(self, state) :
    self.loc = state[:]
```

If they are not always have the same size, then you can rewrite it to:

```
def set_state(self, state) :
    self.loc[:len(state)] = state[:]
```

As for `do_move` method, there are already good answers about it, so I won't comment it. So I will go to the last method of `board` which is `print_board`.
Consider using `__repr__` or `__str__` instead. 
So you can then in your `main` insted of this:

```
tf_board.print_board()
```

You will be able to do this:

```
print tf_board
```

Now we can switch to **player** class

```
move_rules = {1 : ['right', 'down', 'downright',],\
```

You don't need line breaks here, so just remove them.

```
def all_same_pieces(line) :
    elem = line[0]
    flag = True
    for piece in line :
        if piece != elem :
            flag = False
    return flag
```

Can be simplified to:

```
def all_same_pieces(line) :
    elem = line[0]
    return all(x == elem for x in line)
```

Line breaks again, you don't need them here:

```
checklists = [[state[0], state[4], state[8]],\
```